# Only show coding-system in mode-line when not utf-8-unix

Tags: mode-line, character-encoding

I’m trying to save space in my mode-line. 99% of the files I edit are in UTF-8 format with Unix line endings (coding system `utf-8-unix`). I don’t need the ‘U’/‘U:’ indicator in my mode-line in these cases, but I would like it to be there (in a warning face if possible) if I’m editing a file in any other coding system.

How can I hide this in my mode line only if it’s `utf-8-unix`? (FWIW I’m using `smart-mode-line`, if that helps.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you could use to customize the mode-line coding indicator:

```el
(setq-default
 mode-line-mule-info
 `(""
   (current-input-method
    (:propertize ("" current-input-method-title)
                 local-map ,mode-line-input-method-map
                 mouse-face mode-line-highlight))
   (:eval
    (propertize
     (cond
      ((memq buffer-file-coding-system '(utf-8-unix)) "")
      (t (propertize "%z" 'face 'warning)))
     'help-echo 'mode-line-mule-info-help-echo
     'mouse-face 'mode-line-highlight
     'local-map mode-line-coding-system-map))
   (:eval (mode-line-eol-desc))))
```